# save state of checkbox

Tags: android, listview

i havetwo activty in which activity b has the contact details when user select the checkbox,data is stored in the string in the activity a,for more selction when user goes back to activity b,previously selected contacts are shown checked,that means their state ramain saved,how to do that

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.smscampaign;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    ArrayList<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> phno1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> phno0 = new ArrayList<String>();
    MyAdapter ma;
    Button send;
    ListView lv ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setContentView(R.layout.get);
        TextView txt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        getAllCallLogs(this.getContentResolver());
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        ma = new MyAdapter();
        lv.setAdapter(ma);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);




    }

/*  @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        // Save ListView state
        Parcelable state = lv.onSaveInstanceState();

        // Set new items
        lv.setAdapter(Baseadapter);

        // Restore previous state (including selected item index and scroll position)
        lv.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    }*/

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contact_main, menu);

        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.addPage:

    break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        StringBuilder checkedcontacts = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.println( ma.mCheckStates.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++)

        {
            if (ma.mCheckStates.get(i) == true) {
                phno0.add(phno1.get(i).toString());
                checkedcontacts.append(name1.get(i).toString());
                checkedcontacts.append("\n");

            } else {
                System.out.println("..Not Checked......"
                        + name1.get(i).toString());
            }

        } 
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, checkedcontacts, 1000).show();
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("name", phno0);

        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);


        finish();
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ma.toggle(arg2);
    }

    public void getAllCallLogs(ContentResolver cr) {

        Cursor phones = cr.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String name = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            System.out.println(  phoneNumber);
            name1.add(name);
            phno1.add(phoneNumber);
        }

        phones.close();
    }

    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
            CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
        private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        TextView tv1, tv;
        CheckBox cb;

        MyAdapter() {
            mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(name1.size());
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
         // Save ListView state

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return name1.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View vi = convertView;
            if (convertView == null)
                vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            tv.setText(name1.get(position));
            tv1.setText( phno1.get(position));
            cb.setTag(position);
            cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
            cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

            return vi;
        }

        public boolean isChecked(int position) {
            return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
        }

        public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
            mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
        }

        public void toggle(int position) {
            setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass String In Intent.
try this Code For Ex:
You need to pass it as an Intent

```
  ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();  
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityName.this, Second.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("key", mylist);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then extract it from your new activity like this:

```
Intent i = getIntent();  
ArrayList<String> list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("key");
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: where i have to add this above code..,didn't get it

Comment: the First Code Snippet you have to add in Activity Where you want to store The CheckBox List.And The Another Code Snippet you have to put in the Another Activity where to want Show the List.